# does NestJS rabbitmq microservice requires the application to listen to all incoming message patterns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

I have two rabbitmq nestjs microservices. Both services listening to the same queue

Message flow:

```
MyQueue(pattern: events) -> ServiceA -> MyQueue(pattern: logs) -> ServiceB
```

The message flow is working fine but i am getting following error log when ServiceA sends a message to ServiceB

```
[Server] There is no matching event handler defined in the remote service.
```

Now the question is, in NestJS is it assumed that a service should listen to all incoming message patterns? If no then how to handle this error?

**Code:**

```
/* 
* ServiceA
*/ 

import {EventPattern} from '@nestjs/microservices';

export class EventsController {
  private client: ClientProxy;

  constructor() {
    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create(getRabbitMQClientOptions());
  }

  @EventPattern('events')
  handleEvents(data) {
    this.client.emit('logs', data);

    // process
  }
}

/* 
* ServiceB
*/ 

import {EventPattern} from '@nestjs/microservices';

export class LogsController {

  @EventPattern('logs')
  handleLogs(data) {
    // handle logs
  }
}
```

**Possible solution:**

Use different queues. But then i have to change a lot of code

Note:
NestJS code that logs the error if it doesn't find the matching handler. [Github code link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/server/server.ts#L98.)